# Do Groups in Google Apps for Your Domain archive email like in Google Groups?

Tags: email, google-workspace, google-groups

In Google Apps for Your Domain, Groups of users may be created to act as a mailing list.

Right now, we're still using a separate Google Group to archive our email discussions.  I'd like to do away with that separate mailing list, and use the integrated Groups feature.

Does the Groups feature of Google Apps provide an email archiving feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Google Apps groups are simply mailing lists that send email to all members. Archiving is up to the individuals receiving the list mail. Google Apps Groups don't provide a centralized location for mail; they're not like Google Groups in that regard.

Comment: I was afraid that was so.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Now I'm hoping they'd integrate Google Groups to Google Apps..

Comment: I haven't heard anything, and wouldn't hold my breath. It has to be something that a large number of companies want, but I think they'll defer that kind of functionality to Wave.

Answer (score 4):

Longer answer: Yes. They didn't at the time you asked the question, but as of the 8th December 2009, the Groups feature of Apps got a huge upgrade, and is now almost the same as Google Groups. It's only available for Premium or Education editions though.

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/join-this-group-google-groups-joins.html

Comment: Woohoo! I hope they roll this out to Standard edition soon! =D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work-around, which seems to work very well:

- Create an email account for something like management@company.com. Then create a group such as management-dl@company.com.
- Forward the email, while keeping a copy from management@company.com to management-dl@company.com.

Voila!